# import scala.util.Success (or Failure) lead to an "error: value util is not a member of String"

Tags: scala

my environment shows that I'm using `2.12.10` Scala and `3.1.1` Spark versions:

```
scala: String = 2.12.10
spark: String = 3.1.1
```

However, my following code refuse to `import scala.util.Failure` and `import scala.util.Success`
while both exists for a long time: I can see them mentioned, here: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/util/Success.html

```scala
import java.util.Map;
import fr.ecoemploi.application.etude.swagger.invoker._
import fr.ecoemploi.application.etude.swagger.model.Commune;
import fr.ecoemploi.application.etude.swagger.api.CogControllerApi;
import fr.ecoemploi.application.etude.swagger.invoker.CollectionFormats._
import fr.ecoemploi.application.etude.swagger.invoker.ApiKeyLocations._

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")
implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

import scala.util.Failure
import scala.util.Success

//import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
//import scala.concurrent.Future

val apiInvoker = ApiInvoker()
val cogService = CogControllerApi("http://localhost:9090")
val request = cogService.obtenirCommunes(2022);

val response = apiInvoker.execute(request)

response.onComplete {
    case Success(ApiResponse(code, content, headers)) =>
        System.out.println(s"Status code: $code}")
        System.out.println(s"Response headers: ${headers.mkString(", ")}")
        System.out.println(s"Response body: $content")
        
    case Failure(error @ ApiError(code, message, responseContent, cause, headers)) =>
        System.err.println("Exception when calling CogControllerApi#obtenirCommunes")
        System.err.println(s"Status code: $code}")
        System.err.println(s"Reason: $responseContent")
        //System.err.println(s"Response headers: ${headers.mkString(", ")}")
        error.printStackTrace();

    case Failure(exception) => 
        System.err.println("Exception when calling CogControllerApi#obtenirCommunes")
        exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

```
<console>:40: error: value util is not a member of String
       import scala.util.Failure
                    ^
<console>:41: error: value util is not a member of String
       import scala.util.Success
                    ^
<console>:55: error: not found: value Success
           case Success(ApiResponse(code, content, headers)) =>
                ^
<console>:60: error: not found: value Failure
           case Failure(error @ ApiError(code, message, responseContent, cause, headers)) =>
                ^
<console>:67: error: not found: value Failure
           case Failure(exception) =>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Sounds like you have a variable `scala` somewhere which is a `String` and it's in scope before the imports. Get rid of the variable or use `imprt _root_.scala.util.xxx`.

Comment: Thanks. It's a good workaround. Must be Apache Zeppelin, that surely redefines `scala` somewhere.